# GitHub API V3 : what is the difference between pushed_at and updated_at?

Tags: api, github

Looking to V3 API Repos (GET /repos/:owner/:repo) we have 3 datetime :

```
  "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
  "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
```

to have a fast example just link this https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap

What is the difference between pushed_at and updated_at ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**UPDATE**: the behavior described below wasn't intended. `pushed_at` will be updated any time a commit is pushed to any of the repository's branches. `updated_at` will be updated any time the repository object is updated, e.g. when the description or the primary language of the repository is updated. It's not necessary that a push will update the `updated_at` attribute -- that will only happen if a push triggers an update to the repository object. For example, if the primary language of the repository was Python, and then you pushed lots of JavaScript code -- that might change the primary language to JavaScript, which updates the repository object's `language` attribute and in turn updates the `updated_at` attribute. Previously, the primary language was getting updated after every push, even if it didn't change (which wasn't intended), so it triggered an update to `updated_at`.

---

The difference is that `pushed_at` represents the date and time of the **last commit**, whereas the `updated_at` represents the date and time of the **last change** the the repository. A change to the repository might be a commit, but it may also be other things, such as changing the description of the repo, creating wiki pages, etc. In other words, commits are a subset of updates, and the `pushed_at` timestamp will therefore either be the same as the `updated_at` timestamp, or it will be an earlier timestamp.

Comment: It's worth noting that these values apply to the entire repository. If an author updates say their "dev" branch this will update the "updated_at" attribute even though the default_branch (usually master) has not been pushed to.

Comment: Strangely, I have noticed that the `pushed_at` flag gets updated even if anyone happens to open a `pullrequestevent` on any of the focal repository's branches (even without merging or closing it). The opened pull request can come from any remote fork. I am not sure why this us happening, since, a per my understanding, no commit is being made on any of the repos' branch in this particular case.

Comment: I think updated_at might be getting bumped even when the repository gets starred by someone. Or at least that's what my findings suggest.