# How can I find the latest commit from forked repos on github?

Tags: git, github

For example I find a framework that is not maintained anymore but lots of forks. I want to see the more recent forks only. Network Graph is not available if its large.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with a curl:

```
curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/forks
```

For instance, the angular forks are:

```
curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/forks
```

You can add a sort parameter `?sort=<oldest|newest|stargazers>`, but the default one is the `newest`.

Answer (score 24):

I was looking for the same thing, and came across the following website that will list all forks, and latest commit date, stars, forks, issues, etc. A little annoying that GitHub themselves don't offer this (other than via commandline or their API).

https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html

Alternatively, you can use the following website:

https://gitpop2.vercel.app/

I am not affiliated with either.

Answer (score 3):

[Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks) can list forks, and the default order is `newest`.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add, that in addition to just seeing all possible forks (with the default GitHub API sort of *newest* first), a JSON tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) can be used to show only forks with modifications.

There's a fast way, down below, by just comparing created_at and pushed_at as strings.

I also made a JQ script which allows you to say "how much newer" one date field is compared to another. It take an arbitrary number of seconds as a threshold to meet your definition of "modified":

**getModifiedForks.jq**:

```
# $ageThresholdInSeconds passed in from command-line, like `jq --arg ageThresholdInSeconds 10 -f <this-file>`
def selectOnlyModifiedForks:
    ((.updated_at | fromdate) - (.created_at | fromdate)) as $ageDiffInSeconds
    | select(
        $ageDiffInSeconds > ($ageThresholdInSeconds | tonumber)
    )
;

[
    .[]
    | selectOnlyModifiedForks
    | {
        html_url: .html_url,
        updated_at: .updated_at
    }
]
| sort_by(.updated_at)
| reverse
```

To see only repositories that were modified at least 2 days (`172800` seconds) after the fork,

```
% curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/dedupeio/csvdedupe/forks
| jq --arg ageThresholdInSeconds 172800 -f getModifiedForks.jq
```

| html_url | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://github.com/rpatil524/csvdedupe | 2019-11-15T01:38:35Z | 2021-02-07T06:15:40Z |
| https://github.com/VirtualClarity/csvdedupe | 2020-05-05T13:43:21Z | 2020-05-08T22:41:00Z |
| https://github.com/DMells/csvdedupe | 2019-02-12T08:08:37Z | 2019-10-24T15:57:46Z |
| https://github.com/skyline-ai/csvdedupe | 2019-03-28T08:21:51Z | 2019-04-16T09:34:19Z |

I piped the JSON output into [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#why-csvkit) for prettier viewing:

```
% <JSON-output> | in2csv -f json | csvlook
```

**updated_at or pushed_at?**

Considering @Carl G's comment:

> Can you just use `pushed_at > created_at`?
>
> ```
> curl -X GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/d-a-n/react-native-webbrowser/forks' \
> | jq '[ .[] 
>       | select(.pushed_at > .created_at) 
>       | {html_url: .html_url, pushed_at: .pushed_at} ] 
>       | sort_by(.pushed_at) 
>       | reverse
>      '
> ```

Yes, that's very quick and easy, thank you!

| Link_to_fork | created_at | c_lt_p | pushed_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Mbompr](https://github.com/Mbompr/react-native-webbrowser) | 17-10-09T16:48:14 | t | 19-10-13T10:05:25 |
| [initz](https://github.com/initz/react-native-webbrowser) | 18-05-08T13:01:10 | t | 18-05-08T13:08:51 |
| [thanhzusu](https://github.com/thanhzusu/react-native-webbrowser) | 18-01-13T14:12:33 | t | 18-01-16T14:18:34 |
| [lambaosk8](https://github.com/lambaosk8/react-native-webbrowser) | 18-01-12T04:15:06 | t | 18-01-13T11:26:20 |
| [jatinkatyal13](https://github.com/jatinkatyal13/react-native-webbrowser) | 18-01-10T20:02:40 | t | 18-01-10T20:10:40 |
| [dnewcome](https://github.com/dnewcome/react-native-webbrowser) | 17-06-07T22:15:25 | t | 17-08-29T21:24:51 |
| [evenmatrix](https://github.com/evenmatrix/react-native-webbrowser) | 17-07-18T15:15:19 | t | 17-07-18T15:40:14 |
| [matthewfbenjamin](https://github.com/matthewfbenjamin/react-native-webbrowser) | 17-01-24T01:09:33 | t | 17-01-24T14:54:27 |

As a caveat, there seems to be [some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15922637/246801) around which would represent "more freshness", updated_at or pushed_at.

Comment: Can you just use pushed_at > created_at? `curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/d-a-n/react-native-webbrowser/forks | jq '[ .[] | select(.pushed_at > .created_at) | {html_url: .html_url, pushed_at: .pushed_at} ] | sort_by(.pushed_at) | reverse'`