# Get current date and time in GitHub workflows

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow for releasing nightly snapshots of the repository. It uses [the create-release action](https://github.com/actions/create-release). This is how the workflow file looks right now:

```yaml
name: Release Nightly Snapshot

on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"

jobs:
  build:
    name: Release Nightly Snapshot
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master Branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'master'
      - name: Create Release
        id: nightly-snapshot
        uses: actions/create-release@latest
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: 'nightly snapshot'
          release_name: 'nightly snapshot'
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

I want `tag_name` and `release_name` to use the current date and time, instead of hard-coded values. However, I couldn't find any documentation on it. How should I do it?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From [this post](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-can-I-set-an-expression-as-an-environment-variable-at/m-p/41804/highlight/true#M4751) you can create a step that [set its output](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) with the value `$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')`

Then use this output using `${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}`. The following show an example for environment variables and for inputs :

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
name: build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Example
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      - name: Test with environment variables
        run: echo $TAG_NAME - $RELEASE_NAME
        env:
          TAG_NAME: nightly-tag-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
          RELEASE_NAME: nightly-release-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
      - name: Test with input
        uses: actions/hello-world-docker-action@master
        with:
          who-to-greet: Mona-the-Octocat-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
```

Outputs :

```
* Test with environment variables
nightly-tag-2020-03-31 - nightly-release-2020-03-31

* Test with input
Hello Mona-the-Octocat-2020-03-31
```

Comment: Not an expert, but I don't understand how this can work, as it seems you mix 2 different concepts. `echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV` is for setting an environment variable, but you define a `name` env variable your script never use. And `${{ steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_id> }}` is for reading the output of a step, but you try to read a `date` output the `date` step never wrote. I would use instead: `run: echo "::set-output name=today::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"` and then `${{ steps.date.outputs.today }}`.

Comment: For me a new step with `run: echo "MY_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)" >> $GITHUB_ENV` and in a subsequent step `${{ env.MY_DATE }}` worked. As described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649397/2584278 .

Comment: The answer doesn't work for me but @Jean-AlexisAufauvre works.

Comment: @chenrui your edit is not working, the original output should works. I don't understand why you remove set-output.

Comment: Seems ::set-output is obsolete now. still looking for how to set build date to an env variable

Comment: @Pete Can you provide a source that `set-output` is obsolete? I cannot find any such information.

Comment: this solution is now deprecated on Github Actions

Answer (score 54):

Here's another way to do this via environment variables (from [this post](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Support-saving-environment-variables-between-steps/m-p/31550#M825)):

```yaml
name: deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set current date as env variable
        run: echo "NOW=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Echo current date
        run: echo $NOW # Gives "2022-12-11T01:42:20"
```

This sets the date as an environment variable, which is useful if you want to consume it in scripts / programs in subsequent steps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `set-env` is deprecated now: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-11-09-github-actions-removing-set-env-and-add-path-commands-on-november-16/

Comment: Thanks, I just use $(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') to set a temporary build for prerelease packages. e.g. -p:PackageVersion=$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')-preview.

Comment: I think the syntax is different now `echo "NOW=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: use ${{ env.var_name }} to access the environment variables, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env

Answer (score 32):

A clean solution is to use  `${{ github.event.repository.updated_at}}` which is pretty close to current datetime`$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)`

Format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp)
e.g 2022-05-15T23:33:38Z

Pros:

- Doesn't require shell execution
- Directly accessible from all your workflow
- Allows cross-referencing with GitHub events

Cons:

- The serial stays the same when rebuilding on the same commit
- Strict format
  *you can still modify the format in a shell

  e.g. `echo ${{ github.event.repository.updated_at}} | sed 's/:/./g'`*
- Not available with [Act](https://github.com/nektos/act) testing framework
- The value doesn't change on retries as it isn't a repository (Thanks @FabrícioCeolin for pointing this out)

References:
[Github context](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)
[Event object](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/github-event-types)

Comment: Another major downside is the fact that without further formatting this is invalid for a tag name due to the colons.

Comment: I tried this but I get the time of the **previous** update (not the current one, the one the Action runs on)

Comment: I loved this answer. Please add in Cons: If you retry the jobs, the serial stays the same.

Comment: NOTE: The `event.repository.updated_at`-field only seems to be updated when on [rare events like the description of the repo or the primary language changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15922637/299409). Not a common event, it would seem. It could be very old, and unlikely to be the same as the commit time.
The alternative pushed_at is the last timestamp for _any commit or branch_, which also seems like the wrong time for this. 
Instead experimenting with `github.event.head_commit.timestamp`, as it refers to the current change.

Comment: it doesn't work to use in upload-artifact name because colon : is not allowed in the name and to remove it you need to use set-output anyway which is deprecated and why I wanted to do this approach in the first place :D #moment22

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files.

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files)

```yaml
name: deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get current date
        id: date
        run: |
          echo "{date}={$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')}" >> $GITHUB_STATE
      - name: Test with environment variables
        run: echo $TAG_NAME - $RELEASE_NAME
        env:
          TAG_NAME: nightly-tag-${{ env.date }}
          RELEASE_NAME: nightly-release-${{ env.date }}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# Set the date time
- name: Retrieve current Date Time in Singapore TimeZone
        shell: bash
        run: echo "START_TIME=$(TZ=":Asia/Singapore" date -R|sed 's/.....$//')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

# Fetch the date time as Github ENV variable
- name: print date
        run: echo ${{ env.START_TIME }}
```

Output-

```
Mon, 21 Aug 2023 15:34:24
```

***you can change the Timezone as required*

Comment: For completeness, see this Wikipedia page for the list of TZ, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 4):

if `$GITHUB_ENV` doesn't work, use `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead:

```yaml
name: Flutter CI
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing GitHub Actions 
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Set current date as env variable"
        run: |
          echo "builddate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        id: version  # this is used on variable path

      - name: Publishing Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.version.outputs.builddate }}
          name: ${{ steps.version.outputs.builddate }}
          body: "your date"

      - name: print date
        run: |
          echo $DEBUG
        env:
          DEBUG: ${{ steps.version.outputs.builddate }}-DEBUG
          RELEASE: ${{  steps.version.outputs.builddate }}-RELEASE
```