# Using date as an ENV variable in GitHub action

Tags: yaml, github-actions

This is very funny but very frustrating problem. I am using an ENV variable, which specifies date. I provide an ISO 8601 compliant version and in application, I retrieve it and parse. When I specify it in GH action workflow, it is get parsed as a date (rather than a string) and formatted. Therefore, my application parsing fails.

Example:
.github/workflows/rust.yaml

```
env:
        MY_DATE: '2020-10-07T12:00:00+01:00'
run: echo $MY_DATE
```

Result (GH action UI):

```
env:
    TMOU_GAME_END: 10/07/2020 11:00:00

10/07/2020 11:00:00
```

It is specific to GitHub action and their yaml parsing, it works OK on Heroku, on various local setups, etc.

Things I tried and they don't work:

- using no quotes, single quotes ('), double quotes (")
- setting another ENV var, LC_TIME to en_DK.UTF-8
- using !!str shorthand (see https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html, section Example 2.23. Various Explicit Tags); this one fails either with  `The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/rust.yml: Unexpected tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'` or with `The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/rust.yml: The scalar style 'DoubleQuoted | SingleQuoted' on line 29 and column 24 is not valid with the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'`

Is there any help? Any secret parameter I can turn on? Any escaping sequence? I just wanna GH Actions yaml parser to treat the value as a string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Surprisingly, it seems GitHub Actions workflow YAML parser does not fully implement the standard and using explicit typing (like `!!str`) does not work. You can, however, workaround it by setting the environment variable to the desired value not in the YAML file itself but dynamically during workflow execution using a [dedicated workflow command](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

```
steps:
  - name: Dynamically set MY_DATE environment variable
    run: echo "MY_DATE=2020-10-07T12:00:00+01:00" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Test MY_DATE variable
    run: echo ${{ env.MY_DATE }}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this was exactly what I needed.