# How to change a GitHub repository's "updated" date

Tags: git, github

I have a project from a few years ago that I want to upload on GitHub. I figured out how to change commit dates using `git rebase`. However, I couldn't find how to change a repository's "updated" date.

[Example of an "updated" date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuvwQ.png)

I would like this new repository to be placed under already existing repositories. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in "[GitHub API V3 : what is the difference between `pushed_at` and `updated_at`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15922637/6309)":

> `updated_at` represents the date and time of the last *change* the the repository.
>
> A change to the repository might be a commit, but it may also be other things, such as changing the description of the repo, creating wiki pages, etc.

So you cannot exactly set it to any date you want.
Simply pushing your rebased repository would update that date. But only to the "current" date, not one of your choice.